# Undo and Redo documents

Tags: c#, wpf, undo-redo, pdftron

I want to undo and redo the pdf documents, which are viewed using pdftron. This is to be done to the document which are edited during runtime. I am using windows presentation Foundation(WPF) for this project.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/core/guides/features/edit/undoredo/

Comment: I was following this documentation, but couldn't achieve output. I wanted to undo while clicking undo button and redo while clicking redo button.

Comment: You may have to contact PDFTron for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the latest SDK version, and use the pdftron.SDF.UndoManager class, as described here.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/core/guides/features/edit/undoredo/
https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFTronSDK/dotnet/pdftron.SDF.UndoManager.html

Most likely, to start with, you would set this up with just the annotations, and add the snapshot logic in ToolManager perhaps. Then you can add undo/redo buttons to iterate through the snapshots.